# ¿como puedo recuperar todos los puntos de una grafica (sin tener ningún otro dato mas que la pura gráfica) en python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, datos

Estoy usando una librería especifica llamada nmrsim la cual simula espectros de resonancia magnética nuclear, sin embargo el inconveniente es que los datos que regresa con la función td.peaklist() solo proporciona los máximos de la grafica, y yo necesito todos los puntos en genera para poder hacer operaciones posteriores.

intente con las operaciones .get_xdata() y las demás pero me marca un error en el código "instance of tuple has no 'get_xdata' member"

[image: adjunto la grafica que me devuelve el programa]

```
from nmrsim import Multiplet
from nmrsim.plt import mplplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 1200 Hz, 2H, td, J= 7.1, 1.1 Hz
td = Multiplet(1200.0, 2, [(7.1, 2), (1.1, 1)])
print(td.v)
print(td.I)
print(td.J)

print(td.peaklist())

grafica = mplplot(td.peaklist())

grafica.get_xdata()
grafica.get_ydata()
grafica.get_xydata()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `mplplot` retorna los puntos dibujados pero al usar `plt.show()` internamente bloqueara su retorno hasta que se cierre la ventana manualmente. Una posible solución es desactivar y activar el modo interactivo de matplotlib antes y despues de usar `mplplot`, respectivamente:

```py
from nmrsim import Multiplet
from nmrsim.plt import mplplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 1200 Hz, 2H, td, J= 7.1, 1.1 Hz
td = Multiplet(1200.0, 2, [(7.1, 2), (1.1, 1)])

plt.ion()

x, y = mplplot(td.peaklist())
print(x, y)

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```